# Change the datebox date and display the new datebox date in the form containing the data-role datebox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, datebox

I am trying to make a button change the text or value of my datebox form. The value will change if I call $("element").val("value-date") but the form that contains the datebox will not change its text to the value-date. I have refreshed the datebox and that has not worked.
Here is my code

HTML:

```
<div class='container center' style='margin-top:15%; margin-bottom:15%; width:90%; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;'>
        <input placeholder="Enter Date" id='comp_date' type='date' data-role='datebox' name='date' data-options='{"mode": "callbox","useTodayButton":true}'/>
        <a data-role="button" id='pick_today' href="#"  data-theme='e' class="reg_button" style="padding:15px; color:black; margin-bottom:50px;">Now</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
     $("#pick_today").live("vclick",function()
     {
          var today = new Date();
          var month = today.getMonth();
          var day = today.getDate();
          var year = today.getFullYear();
          var todayText = year + "-" + month + "-" day;
          $("#comp_date").val(todayText);
          $("#comp_date").datebox("refresh");
     }
```

Comment: Refer my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12736449/500725)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time spent on this issue, finally got and fixed your problem.

## Your code issues are:

1. Symbol `"+"` is missing on this line

   `var todayText = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;`
2. On the input tag, mode is `calbox` not `callbox`

   `data-options='{"mode": "calbox"`
3. Month calculation should be `+1`. Since January starts with `Zero (0)`

   `var month = today.getMonth()+1;`

### JQuery:

```
$("#pick_today").live("click", function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var month = today.getMonth()+1;
    var day = today.getDate();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var todayText = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    $("#comp_date").val(todayText);
});
```

### HTML:

```
<div class='container center' style='margin-top:15%; margin-bottom:15%; width:90%; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;'>
    <input placeholder="Enter Date" id='comp_date' type='date' data-role='datebox' name='date' data-options='{"mode": "calbox","useTodayButton":true}'/>
    <a data-role="button" id='pick_today' href="#"  data-theme='e' class="reg_button" style="padding:15px; color:black; margin-bottom:50px;">Now</a>
</div>​
```

### USED CSS & JS:

```
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/jquery.mobile-1.0rc3.min.css
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/jquery.mobile-1.0rc3.min.js
http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.css
http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js
```

Refer my **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/3x5PZ/1/)**

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a problem I have been trying to solve for a while

Comment: fwiw, your demo has one small deficiency - day and month are expected to be 2 digit (unless the format has been overridden).  (as easy as var todayText = year + "-" + (month<10?"0":"") + month + "-" + (day<10?"0":"") + day;

Answer (score 1):

You are missing id selector  and binding 'vclick' inseatd of 'click' function and the  function is not properly closed

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/n9HLU/4/

And the correct code is here:

```
$("#pick_today").live("click", function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var month = today.getMonth();
    var day = today.getDate();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var todayText = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    $("#comp_date").val(todayText);
});
```

Comment: Thank you that was my mistake for not putting in the hashtag when correlating the id. This is not working though.

Comment: See the DEM0. Isn't it what you asked for??

Comment: I am asking for the text to change when you click on the now button. Where it says "Month/Day/Year" before you click now on JSFiddle is where I want the date value to display.

Comment: Sorry close. I want to change the text of the $("#comp_date") object. If I change $("#comp_date")'s value the display will still display "Month/Day/Year". If I change the .text of $("#comp_date") then $("comp_date") will still display "Month/Day/Year". I am ultimately trying to get the now button to change the display of the  date input form without using the datebox. I hope I am clear enough